# How to generate self-signed cert for use with Tomcat7

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

**Goal: To use a self-signed cert with my dev Tomcat server.**

Step 1: Create a certificate with openssl following this [Ubuntu certificate guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html):

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

I followed the self-signed NO password guidance.

Step 2: Update Tomcat config file `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
            keystoreFile="/etc/ssl/private/server.key" keystorePass=""
            maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Step 3: Restart Tomcat:

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

Test through Chrome browser on another computer:

**All SSL connections to server are refused**, but standard http connections work.  Error details in Chrome:

```
Google Chrome's connection attempt to [domain] was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
```

I have seen a plethora of instructions on how to get this to work.  But I am confused at the dizzying array of methods.  Not the least is some mention a keystore where others only mention cert files.  Obviously my ignorance of the topic is in play here.  Furthermore, I have a cert but according to many guides, I cannot import my key into a keystore as there is no facility for that.

Both ports `443` and `8443` are open on the server.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the docs, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: @JacobEvans  Yes I have, and it was too fragmented to understand well.  I really need a step-by-step guide.  A LOT of hand holding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat needs an certificate stored in an Java key store (jks). Java comes usually with the `keytool` tool already installed. You should use `keytool` to generate a self-signed certificate like this:

`keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048`

Consult [this site](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html) for more information on the use of keytool.

Comment: Didn't even notice he was generating it with openssl and not keytool

Comment: I created a new key and keystore following the links instructions using `keytool` and generated a keystore and key pair.  I updated the `server config file` to point to keystore and `restarted Tomcat` and I still get the same error - HTTP still works.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: You should take a look in the server logs. I would change the `protocol` parameter to the default value `HTTP/1.1` but without the logs its just a guess. Maybe its just a typo or permission error.

Comment: I assume you are going to HTTPS://server:8443